# Django Admin does not load CSS/JS file in Docker and setting request as cancelled

Tags: python, django, docker

I am using Docker-based Django setup based on `gunicorn`. On accessing admin it is not loading css/js files.

[image]

The `settings.py` looks like below:

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Django serves static files in development mode only. Read the first green box at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/ !

Comment: @KlausD. I already have `DEBUG = True` set true.

Comment: But you are using gunicorn and not `runserver`.

Comment: @KlausD. Pardon my ignorance. I did not know that. What should I do then?

Comment: @KlausD. I ran `python manage.py collectstatic`, it does create `static` folder but still no luck.

Comment: @KlausD. nvm, I rather loaded `runserver` and it worked. But what should I do for production purpose to let admin load properly?

Comment: [Configure a webserver to serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Answer (score 1):

Put following variable in your setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/staticfiles/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

MEDIA_URL = "/mediafiles/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mediafiles")
```

create the appropriate directories in your docker file

```
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME
```

Point your nginx to appropriate directories as follows:

```
 # docker-compose
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 81:81
    depends_on:
      - web
 volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

and finally run

```
docker-compose exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and many other solutions and I was never able to make staticfiles be served properly when using docker until I used the WhiteNoise library. I installed it, add one line in the settings.py file INTALLED_APPS, one in MIDDLEWARE, and one in STATICFILES_STORAGE. Then ran collectstatic, and it worked like a charm!

Follow this instructions and you will be serving static files in no time!
https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I looked for this answer for days and it worked for me. I hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34694505)